# iPad rich text control

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ipad

I'm looking for a solution to allow a user to write text in my iPad app (currently using UITextView) but I would like them to be able to select the font, colour and alignment of particular paragraphs so I basically need a rich text editor of some sort.

What would be the best approach to this? Is there an existing solution or could UITextView be adapted to do this?

Answer (score 0):

There is no rich text control in Cocoa Touch available for developers. You can try [EGOTextView](http://developers.enormego.com/code/EGOTextView) custom control for this.